# Weird behavior when copying objects in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

The following code creates a new `ItemList` called `Second List` by copying the `Item`s from an existing `ItemList` called `First List`. After the `Second List` is created I want to delete all `Item`s from `First List`, my issue is that for some reason when I call the `deleteItemsFromFirstList()` method to delete the items from First List the last `Item` from `Second List` is deleted and moved to `Fist List` so, I ended up with one (1) `Item` in `First List` and with last `Item` missing in `Second List`. In theory `Second List` should have all three (3) items and `First List` should be empty. I hope it makes sense.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
What I want to be able to do is copy the items from First List to Second List, then delete the items from First List but leave First List (empty) in Realm.

Here is the code:

#### Realm Object Models

```
class Item:Object{
    dynamic var basePrice:Double = 0
    dynamic var productName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}

class ItemList: Object {
    dynamic var listName = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

#### Adding and Deleting Methods

```
func newList()     
    let newList = ItemList()
    newList.listName = "Second List"

    if let firstList = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = %@", "First List").first{
        let itemsFromFirstList = firstList.items

        try! realm.write {
            for i in itemsFromFirstList{
                let obj = realm.create(Item.self)
                obj.basePrice = i.basePrice
                obj.productName = i.productName
                newList.items.append(obj)
                realm.add(newList)
            }
        }
    }
}

func deleteItemsFromFirstList(){
    let listToDelete = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = %@", "First List").first

    try! realm.write {
        for i in (listToDelete?.items)! {
            realm.delete(realm.objects(Item.self).filter("productName = %@", i.productName).first!)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Outputs

Existing List: This is how `First List` looks like (Code not shown for its creation)

```
Results<ItemList> (
    [0] ItemList {
        listName = First List;
        createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:32:45 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6100000f4100> (
            [0] Item {
                basePrice = 1;
                productName = Apples;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:32:57 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                basePrice = 2;
                productName = Oranges;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:33:04 +0000;
            },
            [2] Item {
                basePrice = 3;
                productName = Bananas;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:33:13 +0000;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

After `Second List` is created. At this point both lists look identical which is what I want.

```
Results<ItemList> (
    [0] ItemList {
        listName = First List;
        createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:32:45 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6080000f5680> (
            [0] Item {
                basePrice = 1;
                productName = Apples;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:32:57 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                basePrice = 2;
                productName = Oranges;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:33:04 +0000;
            },
            [2] Item {
                basePrice = 3;
                productName = Bananas;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:33:13 +0000;
            }
        );
    },
    [1] ItemList {
        listName = Second List;
        createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6080000f5b00> (
            [0] Item {
                basePrice = 1;
                productName = Apples;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                basePrice = 2;
                productName = Oranges;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
            },
            [2] Item {
                basePrice = 3;
                productName = Bananas;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

After calling the `deleteItemsFromFirstList()` method. Please note that before this call both lists had three (3) `Item`s but now `Second List` has only two and `First List` ended up with one (1). In theory `Second List` should have all three (3) items and `First List` should be empty.

```
Results<ItemList> (
    [0] ItemList {
        listName = First List;
        createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:32:45 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6100000f1f00> (
            [0] Item {
                basePrice = 3;
                productName = Bananas;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:33:13 +0000;
            }
        );
    },
    [1] ItemList {
        listName = Second List;
        createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6100000f6400> (
            [0] Item {
                basePrice = 1;
                productName = Apples;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                basePrice = 2;
                productName = Oranges;
                createdAt = 2017-05-03 01:34:03 +0000;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try deleting the items, since when you add them to a list, you don't actually copy the items themselves in Realm, you just add a reference to the items to your second list.

First you should clarify what do you actually want to achieve. If you want to delete the first list, but not the items of it, delete the ItemList object from Realm and not the Item objects that are elements of ItemList.list.

If you actually want to delete the objects from Realm, you can't just filter for their names, since the names will be the same in both lists, you have to filter for example the createdAt property. If you choose this method, you should change the createdAt property of each item to the same property of the list once you add them to a list, this way you can filter by it.

Comment: @ David Pasztor - What I want to be able to do is copy the items from First List to Second List, then delete the items from First List but leave First List (empty) in Realm. I see your point (method #3), for some reason I thought I was making copies in Realm. Quick question. If I'm understanding this correct, what you are suggesting in method #3 is to change the `createdAt` property for all items in `First List` before creating the reference in `Second List` so later on I can filter and delete them, correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Unless you explicitly call a write transaction, any Realm objects that you have created/changed since the last write are not persisted in Realm.
You cannot just create reference in Second List, you actually need to create copies of all items in First List. For these copies, the createdAt property should be the time when you copy them and you need to add these as well after adding them to SecondList.

Comment: By using the createdAt property in the `deleteItemsFromFirstList  method` seem to be working fine.  Thanks. `realm.delete(realm.objects(Item.self).filter("createdAt = %@", i.createdAt).first!)`